# How to fix slow PDO mssql connecton in linux php?

Tags: php, sql-server, linux

Trying to connect to my MS-SQL Server, trough PHP 7.2.
With PDO SQL SRV 5.6.1 - but is really slow, 2-3 secounds just to make the connection

Tryed upgrading the PDO SQL SRV driver, from 5.3 to 5.6 - no difference. Also tryed using the SQLSRV driver, thats even slower.

```
echo date('h:i:s');
echo "<br />";
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=thedb", "thesa", "thepass");
echo date('h:i:s');
```

That piece of code, takes 2-3 secounds to run - first I thought it was my queries that what slow, but it is the connection. Anyway to speed it up?

Comment: Have you tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: "The PDO_SQLSRV extension is only compatible with PHP running on Windows. For Linux, see ODBC and » Microsoft's SQL Server ODBC Driver for Linux."

Comment: Are there any guides around for the ODBC? Cant seem to find any? Both the setup and how to use?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.connection.php